# CentOS 6 init script doesn't work properly

Tags: linux, centos, boot, init.d, god

I'm setting up my ruby production server based on CentOS 6. I need a process called god (which is a process monitoring tool) to start at boot. I'm using an init script that I found [here](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/11/02/monitoring-delayed_job-with-god-on-centos/). Just as stated in the guide I ran:

```
chkconfig --add god
```

and then

```
chkconfig --level 345 god on
```

After this if I run "`service god start|restart`" everything works. It loads the available configurations and brings up the related processes (if they are not running).

Problem is it doesn't work at boot. If I reboot the system, then I do "`ps -aux | grep god`". At this point "god" is running but apparently it didn't load the configuration files.

If i run again `service god restart`, it loads everything without problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check all your relevant logs first.

Answer (score 1):

The most propable reason for this is that there is a path missing during the boot-process.

Also check the shell that is being called in the first line of the init-script.

It should read:

`#!/bin/sh`